# Read a byte array from a redirected process

Tags: c#, image-processing, process, arrays

I am using the process object in c#

I am also using FFMPEG.

I am trying to read the bytes from the redirected output. i know the data is an image but when I use the following code I do not get an image byte array.

this is my code:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.8:554/video_1 -an -f image2 -s 360x240 -vframes 1 -";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output);
```

The 1st bytes are not the header of a jpeg?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think treating the output as a text stream is not the right thing to do here. Something like this worked for me, just directly read the data off the output pipe, it doesn't need conversion.

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
// take frame at 17 seconds
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -i c:\temp\input.mp4 -an -f image2 -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:17 pipe:1";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();

FileStream baseStream = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream as FileStream;
byte[] imageBytes = null;
int lastRead = 0;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{            
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    do
    {
        lastRead = baseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, lastRead);
    } while (lastRead > 0);

    imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
}

using (FileStream s = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\singleFrame.jpeg", FileMode.Create))
{
    s.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Why 4096? Can I use a larger number for buffer?

Comment: Yes, you can use a different size within reason.